# Create a Chartjs component in order to use it in multiple component - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

**Hi everyone,**

I am doing a data visualisation and I want to use the library Chart.JS.

Because I will be doing a lot of charts, I wanted to create a shared component for my chart that I would be using every time I want to show a chart in my app.

The issue with this idea is that when I call the component `<app-graph>` in a different component, the last data's passed is the one saved and show on the chart.

**This is my question** : How and what is the best practice to show multiple chart? Should I change my graph component or should I declare a new chart every time I need a chart and forget about my chart component?

I tried to change the id dynamically also but it didn't worked.

Sometimes it works, when it initialised with the ng serve. For the moment I am creating a new chart every time.

I made this component and it's available here :

`graph.component.ts` :

```
 @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;
  @Input() chartType: string;
  @Input() chartDatasets: Array<any>;
  @Input() chartLabels: Array<any>;
  @Input() chartOptions: any;

  public theChartType: string;
  public theChartDatasets: Array<any> = [];
  public theChartLabels: Array<any> = [];
  public theChartOptions: any;

  public chart: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Graph component');
    this.updateDataforChart();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
      this.chart = null;
      this.updateDataforChart();
    }
  }

  updateDataforChart() {
    // Data that will be passed
    this.theChartType = this.chartType;
    this.theChartDatasets = this.chartDatasets;
    this.theChartLabels = this.chartLabels;
    this.theChartOptions = this.chartOptions;

    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myChart');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: this.theChartType,
      data: {
        labels: this.theChartLabels, // your labels array
        datasets: [{
          data: this.theChartDatasets, 
          borderColor: '00AEFF',
          fill: true
        }],
      },
      options: this.theChartOptions,
    });

  }
```

`graph.component.html` :

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <!-- <canvas id="customChart" #customChart>{{ chart }}</canvas> -->
    <canvas id="myChart" #myChart >{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

When I call the component :

```
<app-graph [chartType]="chartType" [chartDatasets]="chartDatasets" [chartLabels]="chartLabels" [chartOptions]="chartOptions">    
</app-graph>
```